# JQuery dataTable header fixed issue

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jQuery dataTable. I want to fixed the header when user scroll down with in specific div. Here is my code and is here my image.

[image]

Here is the code sample

```
$('#tblProducts').DataTable({
                  // "scrollY": 400,
                    // "scrollX": true,
                    fixedHeader: {
                        header: true
                        //,fixedHeader:$('#tblProducts').outerHeight()
                    },
                    "paging": false,
                    "fixedColumns": {
                        leftColumns: 1
                    },
                    "searching": false
                   // "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]]
                });
```

The link i am using are here

```
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/js/dataTables.fixedHeader.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/fixedheader/3.1.2/css/fixedHeader.dataTables.min.css">
```

[image]

```
<table id="tblProducts" class="display nowrap table table-striped" style="width:100%;">
                    <thead class="table-thead">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-1 col-lg-1">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll" class="checkboxCSS" name="SelectAll" />
                            </th>
                            <th style="width:120.6945px !important;">
                                UPC
                            </th>
                            <th style="width:120px !important;">
                                Product Name
                            </th>
                            <th style="width:100px !important">
                                HAAD Code
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Barcode
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Status
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Batch #
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Expiry
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Avb.Qty
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Purchased
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Initialize Qty
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Sold
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Adjusted
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Return Out
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Return In
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Focr
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Add/Discard
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                Real CP
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Unit Cost
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Unit Sale
                            </th>

                            <th>
                                Invoice#
                            </th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Order Id</th>

                            <th>
                                Order Date
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                Receive Date
                            </th>
                            <th style="width:100px !important;">
                                VendorName
                            </th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.InventoryDetail.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => @Model.InventoryDetail[i].Id, new { name = "Id" })
                        var UPC = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].UPC;
                        var Id = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].Id;
                        var ProductName = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].ProductName;
                        var GreenrainCode = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].GreenrainCode;
                        var Barcode = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].Barcode;
                        var Description = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].Description;
                        var Status = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].Status;
                        var BatchNo = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].BatchNo;
                        string[] expirydate = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].ExpiryDate.ToString().Split(' ');
                        var ExpiryDate = expirydate[0];
                        var Quantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].Quantity;
                        var FocrQuantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].FocrQuantity;
                        var SoldQuantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].SoldQuantity;
                        var PurchasedQuantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].PurchasedQuantity;
                        var InitializeQuantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].InitializeQuantity;
                        var AdjustQuantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].AdjustQuantity;
                        var ReturnQty = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].ReturnQty;
                        var ReturnIn = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].ReturnIn;
                        var CostPrice = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].CostPrice;
                        var SalePrice = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].SalePrice;
                        var OrderId = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].OrderId;
                        var _addeddQuantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].AddedQuantity;
                        var _discardedQuantity = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].DiscardQuantity;
                        string[] _receiveDate = @Model.InventoryDetail[i].ReceivedDate.ToString().Split(' ');
                        var ReceiveDate = _receiveDate[0];
                        var StockType = _enumList.Where(x => (int)x == Model.InventoryDetail[i].TypeId).Select(x => x);  // @Model.InventoryDetail[i].Type;
                       // var _purchaseQty = Model.InventoryDetail[i].getpurchaseQuantity();
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>

                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => @Model.InventoryDetail[i].IsRowChecked, new { name = "IsRowChecked", @class = "checkboxCSS" })
                                    @if (Model.InventoryDetail[i].Quantity > 0)
                                    {
                                        <a href='/BarcodePrinting.aspx?StockId=@Model.InventoryDetail[i].Id' target="_blank" class="btn btn-default print-btn">Print Full PO Barcode</a>
                                    }
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @UPC
                                </td>
                                <td style="white-space:normal;">
                                    @ProductName
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @GreenrainCode
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Barcode
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Status
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @BatchNo
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @ExpiryDate
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Quantity
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @PurchasedQuantity
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @InitializeQuantity
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @SoldQuantity
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @AdjustQuantity
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @ReturnQty
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @ReturnIn
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @FocrQuantity
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @(_addeddQuantity + "/" + _discardedQuantity)
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    @Model.InventoryDetail[i].RealCostPrice
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.InventoryDetail[i].CostPrice)
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.InventoryDetail[i].SalePrice)
                                </td>

                                <td style="white-space:normal;">
                                    @Model.InventoryDetail[i].InvoiceNumber
                                </td>
                                <td>@StockType.FirstOrDefault()</td>
                                <td>@OrderId</td>
                                <td>
                                    @(Model.InventoryDetail[i].DatePurchase == null ? "" : Model.InventoryDetail[i].DatePurchase.Value.ToShortDateString())
                                </td>
                                <td>@ReceiveDate</td>
                                <td style="white-space:normal;">
                                    @Model.InventoryDetail[i].VendorName
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>

                    }
                </table>
```

Please review my table as i am using mvc razor syntax for rendering. I am loading this table within a div. I want to fixed the header when user scroll down. How to achieve this i am stuck.

Comment: I used fixedHeader: true and worked for me

Comment: sorry it didn't work for me.

Comment: Show your html code. How you render this table.

Comment: See the updated question.

Answer (score 0):

[Compatibility document](https://datatables.net/download/compatibility) says that fixed header and fixed columns cannot be used  the same table.

So, just delete the part below, then it should be working.

```js
"fixedColumns": {
    leftColumns: 1
},
```

If still it does not work, instead of this

```js
fixedHeader: {
    header: true
}
```

try this

```js
fixedHeader: true
```

Comment: I have used it but it fixed the header at the top of the page. Please review my update question with second image